# Bootstrap label not aligning properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I noticed that if I put a space on my label "Last Name" it does not align properly as I wanted to. It gets split up in a new line. What I want to do is align them horizontally. How can I do it? Here are the codes.

[Refer to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVGvC.png)

```
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="messages"></div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="LastName">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Contact">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="active" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Paid</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select class="form-control" name="active" id="active">
                <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>                    

      </div>
```

Comment: put `col-sm-3` on labels and `col-sm-9` in inputs.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but I have tested this in [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/ETgKqbjetO), and it works as expected.  Is that all of your HTML for that form?

Comment: @alex that would be the correct answer, except I don't think the OP has posted all of their code.. check my earlier comment and follow the link.. it works as expected without me changing anything.

Comment: @T_Roy I agree, I also don't see issue myself.

Comment: I believe this is a problem dealing with the `width` of the entire form.  What is the CSS for `modal-body`?

Comment: I tried changing width but could not achieve what picture shows. I think OP should expect element to see what other styles are applied to that/those label(s).

Comment: @alex's first solution worked perfectly. Thanks to you both! :-D